# LinqPad - Export to Excel with NO formatting

Tags: c#-4.0, export-to-excel, linqpad

I found this bit of code to export my data results to Excel:

```
List<User> users  = ....
var filename = "test.html";

var writer = LINQPad.Util.CreateXhtmlWriter();
writer.Write(users);

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, writer.ToString());

// Open the file in excel
Process.Start("Excel" , filename);
```

This exports the data in Formatted mode.  What's the code to replicate just "Export > Export To Excel"?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This functionality is not currently exposed for `XhtmlWriter`, but there's a `WriteCsv` method in `LINQPad.Util` that might do what you want:

```
Util.WriteCsv (Customers, @"c:\temp\customers.csv");
```